# MAX Date range in SQL

Tags: sql, date, numeric-limits

MAX Date range from multiple records

I have a table like below.

```
Customer Publication Start Date   End Date   
 1 S0048    DLD         01-JAN-2013   15-NOV-2013
 2 S0048    DLD         03-MAR-2013   31-DEC-2013
 3 S0048    SLD         01-FEB-2013   31-DEC-2013
 4 S0048    SLD         01-FEB-2013   30-NOV-2013
 5 S0145    DLD         01-JAN-2013   01-MAR-2013
 6 S0145    DLD         02-FEB-2013   28-NOV-2013
```

I need to get the result by giving end date range.
Ex: If input : `end date 01-NOV-2013  to 30-NOV-2013` (Searching who are expiring with in NOV month)

Results should be

```
S0145    DLD         02-FEB-2013   28-NOV-2013
```

Please note that 1st and 4th records should not be there as they have renew their publication subscription period.

How can I get these result. please help.

Dear All, I can get the data for a given date range. But it returns 1 , 4 ,6 . I need only record 6 to be return. Cause i need the latest date range for a specified customer for a publication.(Highest date range of each customer each publication). As to my input (searching the November month end dates). 1 is not necessary as that customer had extended the 'DLD' period in 2. it is same in 4th record. 4th do not need as it extended (renew) in record 3

Comment: Did you mean SQL Server? are your dates really stored as a String??

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name  I'm using oracle

Comment: @Mostly I'm using plsql

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use `STR_TO_DATE` for this purpose:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

For instance:

```
SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(`Start Date`, '%d-%b-%Y')) FROM customers
```

The format specifiers (`%d`, etc.) are listed here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Dear All, I can get the data for a given date range. But it returns

Comment: Dear All, I can get the data for a given date range. But it returns  1 , 4 ,6  .  I need only record 6 to be return. Cause i need the latest date range for a specified customer for a publication.(Highest date range of each customer each publication). As to my input (searching the November month end dates). 1 is not necessary as that customer had extended the 'DLD' period in 2. it is same in 4th record. 4th do not need as it extended (renew) in record 3.

Comment: @Deepa, Thankx a lot. users are testing the report. So far it is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

In Tsql you can write a query as:

```
SELECT T2.customer, 
       T2.publication, 
       T2.startdate, 
       T2.enddate 
FROM   table1 T2 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT t1.customer, 
                          Max(t1.enddate) AS MaxEnddate 
                   FROM   table1 T1 
                   GROUP  BY t1.customer, 
                             T1.publication) T 
               ON T.customer = T2.customer 
                  AND T.maxenddate = T2.enddate 
WHERE  T2.enddate BETWEEN '01-NOV-2013' AND '30-NOV-2013'
```

Update:

```
select hca_agent.account_number agency_code,
       hca_sub.account_number subscriber_code,
       hp_sub.party_name subscriber_name,
       sum(xssl.quantity) qty,
       msi.segment1 Publication_name,
       xssl.start_date Period_from,
       xssl.end_date Period_to-------- I need to get the MAX end date----with the relevant start date 
       from xxwnl_st_subscr_line xssl
       inner join 
       (
        select xssl_inner.subscriber_cust_account_id,
                MAX(xssl_inner.end_date) as MaxEnddate
        from xxwnl_st_subscr_line xssl_inner
        group by xssl_inner.subscriber_cust_account_id) T on
       T.subscriber_cust_account_id = xssl.subscriber_cust_account_id 
       and T.MaxEnddate =  xssl.end_date,
       xxwnl_supp_temp_line xsl,    ----others 
       xxwnl_supp_temp_header xsh,-----others 
       hz_cust_accounts hca_sub,----for customer----- 
       hz_parties hp_sub,----others 
       mtl_system_items_b msi,----for publication----- 
       hz_cust_accounts hca_agent,----others 
       hz_parties hp_agent----others 
       where xssl.supply_line_id = xsl.supply_line_id 
       and xsl.header_id = xsh.header_id 
       and hca_sub.cust_account_id = xssl.subscriber_cust_account_id 
       and hp_sub.party_id = hca_sub.party_id 
       and msi.inventory_item_id = xsl.inventory_item_id 
       and msi.organization_id = oe_sys_parameters.value('MASTER_ORGANIZATION_ID', fnd_profile.value('ORG_ID')) 
       and hca_agent.cust_account_id = xsh.cust_account_id 
       and hp_agent.party_id = hca_agent.party_id 
       and hca_agent.customer_class_code = 'SAGENT' and hca_agent.account_number like '95%' 
       and xssl.end_date between TO_DATE('&FROM_DATE','DD/MON/RRRR')
       AND TO_DATE('&TO_DATE','DD/MON/RRRR') 
       group by hca_agent.account_number , hca_sub.account_number , hp_sub.party_name , msi.segment1 , xssl.start_date , xssl.end_date 
       order by 1,2,3
```

Comment: Hi Deepshikha,  In my case there are more than one table.I found out the table for inner join. but where to place the other table?

Comment: The objective of inner query is to get maximum date for each customer and a given publication. Based on this value the outer query fetches the records from main table where date is between given date range. Now it depends what is your join condition. If it's like you want to add filters to whole result then add join with new tables in outer query.But if you want to change the base records add joins to inner query.

Comment: ---As the comment has limited characters---I am sending my query part by part---If u can please help me.
---PART 01
select hca_agent.account_number agency_code,
       hca_sub.account_number subscriber_code,
       hp_sub.party_name subscriber_name,
       sum(xssl.quantity) qty,
       msi.segment1 Publication_name,
       xssl.start_date Period_from,
       xssl.end_date Period_to-------- I need to get the MAX end date----with the relevant start date

Comment: ----PART 02     
  from xxwnl_st_subscr_line   xssl,------main table
       
       xxwnl_supp_temp_line   xsl,----others
       xxwnl_supp_temp_header xsh,-----others
       hz_cust_accounts       hca_sub,----for customer-----
       hz_parties             hp_sub,----others
       mtl_system_items_b     msi,----for publication-----
       hz_cust_accounts       hca_agent,----others
       hz_parties             hp_agent----others

Comment: ---PART 03
 where xssl.supply_line_id = xsl.supply_line_id
   and xsl.header_id = xsh.header_id
   and hca_sub.cust_account_id = xssl.subscriber_cust_account_id
   and hp_sub.party_id = hca_sub.party_id
   and msi.inventory_item_id = xsl.inventory_item_id 
   and msi.organization_id =
       oe_sys_parameters.value('MASTER_ORGANIZATION_ID',
                               fnd_profile.value('ORG_ID'))
   and hca_agent.cust_account_id = xsh.cust_account_id
   and hp_agent.party_id = hca_agent.party_id
   and hca_agent.customer_class_code = 'SAGENT'
   and hca_agent.account_number like '95%'

Comment: ---PART 05
  
   and  xssl.end_date between TO_DATE('&FROM_DATE','DD/MON/RRRR')AND TO_DATE('&TO_DATE','DD/MON/RRRR')
    group by      hca_agent.account_number ,
       hca_sub.account_number ,
       hp_sub.party_name ,
      
       msi.segment1 ,
       xssl.start_date ,
       xssl.end_date  
   order by 1,2,3

Comment: Can you please help me?

Comment: Write a subquery as "select xssl_inner.subscriber_cust_account_id,MAX(xssl_inner.end_date) as MaxEnddate
from xxwnl_st_subscr_line xssl_inner
group by xssl_inner.subscriber_cust_account_id" to get maximum end date for each customer and then inner join this subqery into your main query with condition "ON xssl_inner.subscriber_cust_account_id = xssl.subscriber_cust_account_id and xssl_inner.MaxEnddate =  xssl.end_date". Hope it helped!!...:)

Comment: select hca_agent.account_number agency_code,
       hca_sub.account_number subscriber_code,
       hp_sub.party_name subscriber_name,
       sum(xssl.quantity) qty,
       msi.segment1 Publication_name,
       xssl.start_date Period_from,
       (select xssl_inner.subscriber_cust_account_id,MAX(xssl_inner.end_date) as MaxEnddate 
       from xxwnl_st_subscr_line xssl_inner group by xssl_inner.subscriber_cust_account_id )  ON t.subscriber_cust_account_id = xssl.subscriber_cust_account_id and t.MaxEnddate = xssl.end_date
  from xxwnl_st_subscr_line   xssl  
       xxwnl_supp_temp_line   xsl